# Mathematical Analysis - problems regarding field axioms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $F = \{0,1,2\}$. Prove that there is exactly one way to deﬁne addition and multiplication so that $F$ is a ﬁeld if $0$ and $1$ have their usual meaning of ($A4$) and ($M4$).

$(A4)$: There exists an element $0 \in F$ such that $0+x = x; \, \forall x \in F$.

$(M4)$: There exists an element $1 \in F$ (and $16 = 0$) such that $1x = x; \, \forall x \in F$.

My main concern is that I don't really understand the question so I have no idea how to start this. Do I have to prove that $A4$ and $M4$ applies to $F$ or prove the other field axioms applies to $F$ so $A4$ and $M4$ are correct?

Comment: You have to find an addition operation and a multiplication operation on $F$ so that 1) With these two operations, $F$ is a field, 2) the 0 element of this field, as prescribed by the axiom A4 is actually the element named 0 in $F$, and 3) the 1 element of this field, as prescribed by the axiom M4, is actually the element named 1 in $F$. Without requirement 2) and 3), it can be done in 6 ways. With those two requirements it can only be done in one way. Of coure, that's up to you to prove.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Filling in the tables, using that:

- $0+x=x+0=x$ for all $x\in F$
- $1\cdot x=x\cdot 1=x$ for all $x\in F$

You can immediately write out the tables as:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
1 & 1 &  \\ \hline
2 & 2 & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
\times & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ \hline
2 & 0 & 2\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Now, how many possibilities are there for the white squares?